# C# Generics, Base Classes and EventArgs, MVP, DI

Tags: c#, events, generics

I know I am probably breaking some rule by attempting this, but I am trying to establish a generic base class with EventArgs. At first, I thought this would be fairly simple. Using a simple legacy (making sure the view is only updated by the presenter) MVP pattern approach, I wanted to do the following. By the way I have some DI(Castle) going on as well but it is not that relevant.

I have a base presenter class

```
 public abstract class PresenterBase<K, T> where K : IView, IPresenter<K, T>
 {
    public event EventHandler<T> StartSomethingEvent;
    public K _view { get; set; }

    public PresenterBase(K view)
    {   
        _view = view;
        _view.Start += new StartEventHandler(OnStartSomethingEventHandler);
    }

    public virtual void OnStartSomething(T args)
    {
        EventHandler<T> handler = StartSomethingEvent;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, args);
        }
    }
 }
```

and a view base class

```
public abstract class ViewBase: IView
{
    public abstract void WriteOutput(string message);

    public event StartEventHandler Start;
}
```

Lets add some interfaces (ooh say it again)
Presenter:

```
public interface IPresenter<V, E>
{
    event EventHandler<E> StartSomethingEvent;

    V _view { get; set; }

    void OnStartSomething(E args);
}
```

View:

```
public interface IView
{   
    event StartEventHandler Start;

    void WriteOutput(string message);
}
```

These seems pretty straight forward (I think)

Now for the actual implementation classes (this is where I hit the gooey tough stuff)

Presenter:

```
public class ImplementedPresenter : PresenterBase<SomeImplementedView, SomeFancyDancyEventArgs>,
    IImplementedPresenter
{
    public ImplementedPresenter(
        IView view)
        : base(view)
    {
       //Some additional wire ups going on that are out of scope.
    }
}
```

View:

```
public class SomeImplementedView : ViewBase
{
    public static event StartEventHandler Start;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Resolve();
        OnReady();
    }

    static void Resolve()
    {
        //DI Stuff
        IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter());
        container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new ListResolver(container.Kernel));

        //Must be resolved before using
        container.Resolve<IImplementedPresenter>();
    }

    static void OnReady()
    {
        StartEventHandler handler = Start;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler();
        }
    }

    public override void WriteOutput(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

But, this probably breaks the Liskov substitution rule.

Since I get the dreaded.

```
"There is no implicit reference conversion from 'SomeImplementedView' to 
'IPresenter<SomeImplementedView,SomeFancyDancyEventArgs>." Message
```

Ugh, This has gotten me before and I can't remember what I did to resolve this. After a few days of pounding my head on this (refactor, refactor, refactor) and thinking "Why am I going though this pain", I asked myself, "self" why not ask the wise folks at StackOverflow, "Anyone have any suggestions to this problem?"

Oh, kind, wonderful, smart, brilliant folks, teach me. Send the wisdom that is only found on this forum.

Revision:
I simplified the code and got it working (See below)

```
public delegate void StartEventHandler();

public class SomeEventArgs : System.EventArgs
{
    private readonly string _somefield;

    public string SomeData { get { return _somefield; } }

    public SomeEventArgs(string somedata)
    {
        _somefield = somedata;
    }
}

public interface IPresenter<V, E>
    where V : IView
{
    event EventHandler<E> StartSomethingEvent;

    V _view { get; set; }

    void OnStartSomething(E args);

}

public abstract class PresenterBase<V, E> : IPresenter<V, E>
    where V : IView
{
    public event EventHandler<E> StartSomethingEvent;

    public V _view { get; set; }

    public PresenterBase(V view)
    {
        _view = view;
        _view.Start += new StartEventHandler(ViewStart_OnStart);
    }

    public void ViewStart_OnStart()
    {
        Process();
    }

    public abstract void Process();

    public void OnStartSomething(E args)
    {
        EventHandler<E> handler = StartSomethingEvent;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, args);
        }
    }
}

public class ImplementedPresenter : PresenterBase<IView, SomeEventArgs>
{
    public ImplementedPresenter(IView view)
        : base(view)
    {
        //Some additional wire ups going on that are out of scope.
    }

    public override void Process()
    {
        OnStartSomething("start data");
    }

    public void OnStartSomething(string somedata)
    {
        SomeEventArgs args = new SomeEventArgs(somedata);
        base.OnStartSomething(args);
    }
}

public interface IView
{
    event StartEventHandler Start;

    void WriteOutput(string message);
}

public abstract class ViewBase : IView
{
    public abstract void WriteOutput(string message);

    public event StartEventHandler Start;
}

public class ImplementedView : ViewBase
{
    public static event StartEventHandler Start;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Resolve();
        OnReady();
    }

    static void Resolve()
    {}

    static void OnReady()
    {
        StartEventHandler handler = Start;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler();
        }
    }

    public override void WriteOutput(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I *am* nice, so even though that title... shudder... and even though you called SO a forum *ugh* I didn't downvote you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This compiles and might give you a working point to build on:

```
public interface IView<V, P, T>
    where V : IView<V, P, T>
    where P : IPresenter<V, P, T>
{ }

public interface IPresenter<V, P, T>
    where V : IView<V, P, T>
    where P : IPresenter<V, P, T>
{ }

public abstract class PresenterBase<V, P, T> : IPresenter<V, P, T>
    where V : IView<V, P, T>
    where P : IPresenter<V, P, T>
{ }

public abstract class ViewBase<V, P, T> : IView<V, P, T>
    where V : IView<V, P, T>
    where P : IPresenter<V, P, T>
{ }

public class ImplementedPresenter : PresenterBase<SomeImplementedView, ImplementedPresenter, SomeFancyDancyEventArgs>
{ }

public class SomeImplementedView : ViewBase<SomeImplementedView, ImplementedPresenter, SomeFancyDancyEventArgs>
{ }
```

Comment: I was able to figure out my problem based on @Enigmativity's suggestion. Basically I simplified the code. The revision is updated on the post

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly requiring that Your class `'SomeImplementedView'` 
would implement (inherit from) -> `IPresenter<K, T>`

You doing this by `'where K : IView, IPresenter<K, T>'`

So You're getting this compiler problem - correctly..

In order to solve this - you should :

```
public class SomeImplementedView : IView, IPresenter<ClassA, ClassB>{}
```

or remove/adjust the constraint on Your generic class -> `where ....`

Comment: Can't tell if you're right as we don't see the definition of SomeImplementedView

Comment: Will - I understand that I'm assuming stuff, but isn't this exactly what the compiler is saying ? than it is not able to CAST SomeImplementedView - to IPresenter<SomeImplementedView,SomeFancyDancyEventArgs> ?

Comment: It definitely appears that way... I'd think OP would catch that, tho. But who knows?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, I will update my issue to include the implementation of the view. Perhaps this will provide some more clarity. Basically, the implemented view does not have any references to presenter code. This is by design since the view should only be updated by the presenter. The updated code will show what I am trying to achieve (I hope).